# Show specific index input and hide others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am stuck in a problem.
i have added a label and input in ng-repeat .when the user clicks the edit i want to show the input and hide the label and its working fine.but when the user clicks new button,it shows the new input but its not working.

Html

```
<tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails">
   <td> <label ng-if="personalDetail.Sname!=''" for="settings" > {{personalDetail.Sname}}</label>
      <input  ng-hide="$index"  type="text" ng-model="personalDetail.Sname" />
   </td>
   <td><label    data-val="{{personalDetail.Settings}}"   for="desc" >{{personalDetail.Settings}}</label>
       <input   Style="display:none" data-val="{{personalDetail.Settings}}"  ng-model="personalDetail.Settings" type="text" value="{{personalDetail.Settings}}"  />
   </td>
   <td> 
       <span  style="cursor: pointer"  ng-click="Edit(personalDetail.Settings,$index)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
       <span   style="cursor: pointer; padding-left:10px;" ng-click="Remove($index)" class ="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" ></span>
   </td>
                                                </tr>
```

Here is the angular

```
$scope.addNew = function (personalDetails) {
            $scope.personalDetails.push({

                'Sname': "",
                'Settings': "",
            });
```

Comment: Where is your new button? What is happening when you are adding new row?

Comment: <input type="button"  class="btn btn-primary addnew pull-right btn-space" ng-click="addNew()"  value=" Add New">

Comment: when i click on new button it shows label data i want to show input @Vivz

Comment: But I think its better if you use an array to hide input like val[$index]=true/false;. Make your last index false to show the input

Comment: if you have any code kindly send it to me .i am beginner .

Comment: how to get that array in angular ?

Answer (score 0):

I created a JSFiddle for this.
[try this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0qgpwvu/1/)

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

 $scope.personalDetails = [ {'Sname': "firsName",
                           'Settings': "firstSettings"},
                           {'Sname': "secondName",
                           'Settings': "secondSettings"},
                           {'Sname': "thirdName",
                           'Settings': "thirdSettings"},];
                           $scope.addNew = function () {
        $scope.personalDetails.push({

            'Sname': "new",
            'Settings': "new",
        });}
});
```

html

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat="personalDetail in personalDetails">
<td> <label ng-show="!personalDetail.edit || personalDetail.edit=false" 
  for="settings" > {{personalDetail.Sname}}</label>
  <input  ng-show="personalDetail.edit"  type="text" ng-
 model="personalDetail.Sname" />
</td>
<td><label    data-val="{{personalDetail.Settings}}"   for="desc" >
{{personalDetail.Settings}}</label>
   <input   Style="display:none" data-val="{{personalDetail.Settings}}"  ng-
model="personalDetail.Settings" type="text" value="
{{personalDetail.Settings}}"  />
</td>
 <td> 
   <button  style="cursor: pointer"  ng-
     click="personalDetail.edit=true">edit</button>

  </td>
   </tr>
   </table>

<button  style="cursor: pointer"  ng-click="addNew()" >new</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This design only works with very simple cases.

I recommend to separate view from input. In the table you show the data.

**Input form**

**Alt1:** Put a simple form above the table with the name and setting as input fields. And a Save and Cancel button. The user can start adding directly. 
Keep the edit button but when you press on it. Populate form above with the current rows data. An change the Save button Update.

**Alt2:** Use ng-repeat-start and ng-repeat-end to create an expandeble row for edit. Inside ng-repeat-end you can place a form. You will get a lot of room for validation messages.